# Strange behaviour when not using dispatcher

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, multithreading

I know that we must use dispatcher whenever you try to access a UI element from different thread, but today I encountered something I want to ask about. Say I have a list populated with objects of class Row ( custom class) and each row is populated with Cell(custom class). each Cell has a property CellWidth. I populate a list inside a ViewModel and then pass it to View where I make ObservableCollection out of a List. Grid's width is bound to CellWidth in UI. So, if I set a width not using Dispatcher ( inside ViewModel), Grid ignores binding, however if I use it , everything works just fine. (Note: exception is not raised when I don't use dispatcher)

The question is: why is it happening? I thought  the only issue dispatcher addresses is threading...

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
{
    IDataTableModel  Table1 = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
            setCellWidth(Table1);
}

private void setCellWidth(IDataTableModel model)
{
    List<double> Widths = new List<double>();
    //initializing Widths with values
    <...>
      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        foreach(var item in model.Rows)
       {
           for(int i = 0; i<item.Cells.Count; i++)
           {
                item[i].CellWidth = Widths[i];
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: *"I populate a list inside a ViewModel and then pass it to View where I make ObservableCollection out of a List"*... does not sound like a very MVVM way of doing things... can you provide your code?

Comment: does your CellWidth property properly fire the PropertyChanged event?